# awk print is ignored when trying to ssh from ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, ssh

when trying to run this command in ruby:

```
puts `#{ssh_line} "cat path.txt | awk '/^server/ {printf("aaa");} {print}'"`
```

the printf is ignored for some reason, but the weird thing is that if i replace the "aaa" with "111", it works ..

Thanks !

Comment: try to add '\n' at the end of the printf string ("aaa\n"), to see if it's not a buffer flushing issue. or could maybe be that "aaa" is taken in this context as a variable name by ruby and is replaced with "" ? (i do not know ruby at all...)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this line works:

```
puts `#{ssh_line} "cat path.txt | awk '/^server/ {printf(\\"aaa\\`");} {print}'"`
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`: `awk '...' path.txt`.